About tensorflow_hub
hi guys i'm successfully import tensorflow_hub.
but when I trey to run this code part
"

**IMAGE_SHAPE = (224, 224)
classifier = tf.keras.Sequential([
hub.KerasLayer(classifier_model, input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE+(3,))**
])"
it generate this error
"---------------------------------------------------------------------------
**> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 3>()
1 IMAGE_SHAPE = (224, 224)
2
3 classifier = tf.keras.Sequential([
4     hub.KerasLayer(classifier_model, input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE+(3,))
5 ])
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/models/sequential.py in add(self, layer, rebuild)
93                 layer = origin_layer
94         if not isinstance(layer, Layer):
95             raise ValueError(
96                 "Only instances of keras.Layer can be "
97                 f"added to a Sequential model. Received: {layer} "
ValueError: Only instances of keras.Layer can be added to a Sequential model. Received: <tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer object at 0x7e7650536c80> (of type <class 'tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer'>)"**
plea

could you plese help

It seems to be some version mismatch issue. Please make sure both TensorFlow and TensorFlow Hub are compactible. As TF 2.x is compactible with TF Hub 0.9 or higher.
print(tf.__version__)
print(hub.__version__)

Try to check these version and then verify it. Another step you can try is to upgrade both of these libraries to latest python packages.
pip install --upgrade tensorflow tensorflow-hub

